# "other" response not collected in Google Forms

Tags: google-forms

I have created a survey using Google Forms many of which are multiple choice with an "other" option at the end and a small box for users to enter their own response.

In the results spreadsheet it only counts the number of users who have selected the other option but does not record the actual text they have entered.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is an as-designed feature, rather than a bug.

Survey results usually don't show all the "other" responses as they are in the main table., because typically the research needs to group and edit them to put responses with similar meaning but different spelling or phrasing together.

Eg, you probably want to group these:
By car
Car
Motor car
Private vehicle